# Number of Solutions to a system of linear equations over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, vector-spaces

I read the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240928/how-many-solution-there-are-finite-field-linear-system) question, but the answer wasn't very clear to me. My question is similar, so I state my question. Could someone clarify the answer to that question, and/or to my question? (If I understand it right, my question is a somewhat more specific case of the other one, right?)

Given an  $n$-dimensional  vectorspace over a finite field ${\mathbb{F}_q}$, how many solutions are there to a system of  $k$  linear equations of full rank (rank $k$) in $n$ variables? (assume $k~<~n$)

(Sorry if the answer to the other question seems clear and the question too simple, but I'm still confused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of solutions is given by  $x_0+W$ where
$W$ is a subspace of the given vector space of dimension $m:=n-k$.
Let $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\}$ be a basis of $W$. Then the map $f:\mathbb{F}_q^m\to x_0+W$, 
$f((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)):=x_0+\sum_{i=1}^m a_i w_i$, is a bijection.
Note finally that 
$\mathbb{F}_q^m$ has $q^m$ elements.